# How to get this nesting working?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I want to nest each element inside the previous at the mid point. How can I do this by indexing a very large list?

> ```
>    {5/24,mid,19/24}/.mid->
>    {7/24,mid,17/24}/.mid->
>    {11/24,mid,13/24}
> ```

(*{5/24, {7/24, {11/24, mid, 13/24}, 17/24}, 19/24}*)
Yes, it's Goldbach that creates the lists. The sample is 5+19, 7+17 and 11+13 with the sum, 24, as the denominator. After the nest: we notice 5,7 on the left and 17,19 on the right. We put the sum of 17,19 divided by 2 (the mid point) into our solver to create the next chain link.
I haven't shown any of that code, because the last time I did, I found out the ones who viewed were math phobic.

Comment: I don't understand the sequence 5, 7, 11,... in the numerators. Ditto for the upper bounds.

Comment: They are primes, since I am experimenting with the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: What I meant was that you reference a very large list. Since the only lists in the question are of the form `{a, mid, b}`, it's unclear where the a's and the b's come from or how the large list is to be modified.

Comment: the triplet is just one of many. The a''s and b's are called p and q in my twin prime solver. Observation: only the last item in a twin, the others are twins with low prime on the left and the high prime on the rigjt---after the nesting. We rely on symmetry.

Comment: I had to Reverse@list to get one working; otherwise it was tough choice. I did remove `mid` and the denominators, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alist = {{5/24, 19/24}, {7/24, 17/24}, {11/24, 13/24}};

Fold[Riffle[#2, {#1}] &, Reverse@alist]
```

$$\left\{\frac{5}{24},\left\{\frac{7}{24},\left\{\frac{11}{24},\frac{13}{24}\right\},\frac{17}{24}\right\},\frac{19}{24}\right\}$$

Comment: +1, I'll do some timings on large lists before accepting either answer.

Comment: To see how it folds step by step: `FoldList[Riffle[#2, {#1}] &, Reverse@alist] // Grid`

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that `mid` is just a placeholder. So, you could do something like this:

```
list = {{11, 13}, {7, 17}, {5, 19}};
Fold[Insert[#2, #1, 2] &, list]
```

`{5, {7, {11, 13}, 17}, 19}`

(I've removed the denominators just for clarity.)

Comment: +1, Can we put a list name on the right?

Comment: yep. see my update.

Comment: hmm. looking at your comment, were you wanting to start with `{5,7,11,13,17,19}` and insert the brackets, or do you have the pairs in a list already like I assumed in my answer?

Comment: I start with the right-most twin prime and build the rest. I'm interested in building a chain of twin primes.